# Store current arraylist before send to server

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, jdbc

(I write this with a translator)

My application putting markers on the map and download geolocation from this place and save in 2 ArrayList, 1 with markers, 2 with lat/long, then all elements from ArrayList sends to MySQL by JDBC.

I would like to extend this application when I have for example 5 position and 5 markers, I would like to restart the device, run the application again and get this 5 position and 5 markers from the last launch and continue downloading position and markers.

But I have no idea how to do it.

I thought that first put the two lists in the "shared preferences", and then send to the MySQL by JDBC.

I have read that the shared preferences do not store files after restarting devices. So it's a bad idea.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Create the file contains JSON object, or serialized data

Comment: it is possible to get back from the database data marker and re-inserting it in the program, list and show it on screen ?